# Log/Graph PHP execution time

Tags: php, metrics

Are there any tools available to log the page load time for a php site?

Mainly looking for something that I can see trends of load times over time, I was considering dumping them into a file using error_log(), but I don't know what I could use to parse it and display graphs

Answer (score 6):

You can record the microtime at the start of execution, hold that variable until the end, check the time, subtract them, and there you have your execution time. Output buffering will be required to make this work in most cases, unless it's a situation in which a particular thing always runs last (like `footer()`).

```
$time_start = microtime_float();

function microtime_float() {
   list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
   return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

//at the start. 

//at the end:

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = round($time_end - $time_start, 4);

echo "Last uncached content render took $time seconds";
```

Comment: microtime_float(); => microtime(true);

Answer (score 3):

Use the Firebug extension for Firefox, it has a Net panel that shows you load times.

If you want to do load testing, apache comes with a utility called apache bench, try ab --help in a console window near you.

Answer (score 0):

See [PEAR Benchmark](http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark/). It allows you to add benchmarks into your code. You can have it dump an HTML table on your pages, or you can loop through the data and write to a log file.